# Bitnami gitlab needs SSH server

Tags: ssh, debian, gitlab, bitnami

I am trying to install [bitnami gitlab](https://bitnami.com/stack/gitlab)
Using Putty I logged using SSH to root account on my debian server, I downloaded installer, added execute to run file and run it and I receive this:

> This installer detects that SSH server is not running. Please start
>   the SSH server to get this application working fine.

Which package it needs?

```
root@PXE:~# ps ax | grep sshd
10750 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: krzysiek [priv]
10754 ?        S      0:00 sshd: krzysiek@pts/1
10948 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
11445 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep sshd
```

Machine

> Linux PXE 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3
>   (2016-07-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016

```
root@PXE:~# dpkg-query --list | grep ssh
ii  libssh2-1:amd64                       1.4.3-4.1+deb8u1                     amd64  
ii  openssh-client                        1:6.7p1-5+deb8u3                     amd64  
ii  openssh-server                        1:6.7p1-5+deb8u3                     amd64  
ii  openssh-sftp-server                   1:6.7p1-5+deb8u3                     amd64  
ii  task-ssh-server                       3.31+deb8u1                          all
```

Comment: Could you check the output of this command? `ps -C sshd`

Comment: `root@PXE:~# ps -C sshd
     PID TTY          TIME CMD
    10948 ?        00:00:00 sshd
    16861 ?        00:00:00 sshd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bitnami developer here.

I've tested in a virtual machine and I get the same error than you about the ssh server.
Then I did:

> sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
>
> sudo apt install openssh-server
>
> sudo apt install openssh-client

Then I ran the installer again and it worked for me.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

SSH server is [disabled by default on Bitnami VM](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/#enable_ssh).

Bitnami [FAQ](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/#enable_ssh) says to:

To enable the SSH server, execute the commands below at the server console:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/ssh.conf.back /etc/init/ssh.conf
sudo start ssh
```

**IMPORTANT**: Before enabling the SSH server, change the default password for security.

Comment: I am not using Bitnami VM, it is my own Debian server where I am trying to install app from run file. Few days before same way I installed Redmine - without any ssh issues